# Where can I find the string.c file itself (to read it)?

Tags: c, string

I'm interested in reviewing some of the functions included in the string library for c, but I can't find the source code (literally, i.e. functions and all) online and I have no idea where to find it.

Thanks.

EDIT:

the [link provided by pmg](http://sources.redhat.com/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/libc/string/?cvsroot=glibc) shows those functions divided into c files, so it's about what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think there is such a file? The fact that there is string.h that you can #include, doesn't mean that there must be string.c.

Comment: As cababunga says, the Standard Library functions are not necessarily written in C. The "string.c" you're looking for (when it exists) will be different from implementation to implementation. Are you looking for a specific implementation?

Comment: Also, your development environment doesn't require source code of your run time. All your string functions are linked from libc.so (or whatever its equivalent on Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [redhat glibc](http://sources.redhat.com/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/libc/?cvsroot=glibc). It appears to be somewhat current.

Comment: Actually I think you found it. If you look the at the string/ dir you'll find the different functions divided into c files, which is pretty much what I needed, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find it in the source code of the `gcc` compiler.

http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/

Answer (score 0):

Usually included with the compiler that you install so this may vary.  Also depends on the operating system your running.  If you're using windows, I recommend you run a Windows search for strings.c and if you're running linux then you can use the find command.

Disregard the file I linked to prior to this edit.  I should have verified the code before sending it.  It didn't apply to your question.  Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for GNU C [string.h](http://linux.die.net/include/string.h)?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the source in any standard libc implementation http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/